Why requireOffset function causing app to crash, even in LaunchedEffect?
I need progress of bottomSheetScaffold in float value, so I am using requireOffset function of bottomSheetScaffold, as progress parameter which was available in material is not available in material3. In Android studio I have live edit turned On, and Whenever I change code anywhere, app is crashing, and Im getting error like trying to get offset before its initialized.
Here is my code

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class,
    ExperimentalMaterialApi::class
)
@Composable
fun PlayerViewBottomSheet(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {


    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

    val screenSize = LocalConfiguration.current.screenLayout
    val progress = remember{ mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val sheetOffset = remember { mutableStateOf(-1f) }

    LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState) {

        snapshotFlow { bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.requireOffset() }.collect { offset ->
            if(sheetOffset.value == -1f){
                sheetOffset.value = offset
            }
            progress.value = 1-(offset/sheetOffset.value)
        }
    }
    
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetPeekHeight = 70.dp,
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState ,
        sheetDragHandle = null,
        sheetShadowElevation = 1.dp,
        sheetShape = RectangleShape,
        sheetContent = {
        BottomSheetContent(
            targetValue = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.targetValue,
            currentValue = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue,
            progress = progress.value
        )
    }) {
        MainScreen()

    }


}



That will be caused by an improperly updated live edit. When built and deployed properly this works fine and doesn't crash. Does this answer your question?

@Leviathan thanks for answering. this answers my question
